# C# HAP how to get redirected url

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

This is an ebay page

> http://www.ebay.com/itm/GRUEN-RUNNING-PRECISION-WRIST-WATCH-/230718830945?pt=Pocket_Watches&hash=item35b7e9f961

I am using C# agility pack to get the 'print' version page from this link . 'Print' link is at the middle right side of this page . Agilitypack is returning this link :

> http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&rt=nc&item=230718830945&si=a8iGAIchyvEbn7KveYFZ5QbEE7o%3D&print=all&category=3940

When I am loading this link its returning another page , not the actual one . Though clicking on 'print' works well . As far as i understand 'print' link is being redirected to another page. I have checked some solution of stackoverflow . not worked for this case . There is a .dll file in the link/path . Any suggestion to solve this problem ??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The link points to `http://cgi.ebay.com/` which redirects to `http://www.ebay.com/itm/` the rest of the URL is identical, so you can just use `string.Replace("http://cgi.ebay.com/", "http://www.ebay.com/itm/")`

Or if you want to do it cleanly, use this code:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(print_url);
HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

string new_print_url = myResp.ResponseUri;
```

Comment: Its returning this link : http://www.ebay.com/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemNext&item=220916389133&info=901 which is not the print version . it should return : http://www.ebay.com/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&rt=nc&item=220916389133&si=a8iGAIchyvEbn7KveYFZ5QbEE7o%3D&print=all&category=31387

Comment: They seem to be performing a detection on referrer in which case your best bet it to just replace the link with the result link like I pointed in my answer.

Comment: After replacing this is the link : http://www.ebay.com/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&rt=nc&item=220916389133&si=jUFRwN71H0uOkxhSG12wXb%2BelcM%3D&print=all&category=31387 ... you can check ... its not the print version

Comment: Well, right now I'm getting error when I manually call that page saying it has expired. Try with a new URL.

Comment: Can you give the replaced string ??

Comment: They definitely do a referrer check, which means you can't get the final URL programatically by using web request.